# Themeroller icon not lining up where I'd expect

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, themeroller

I'm trying to use a themeroller icon on a page and it's not lining up where I'd expect.  If I say:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
                          href="/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"></span>Hello World</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I would expect to see:

```
+Hello World
```

But instead I only see:

```
+
```

Why is this?  And how do I get the result I'm expecting?

Thank you.

Edit 1:
I followed the suggestion below to change the span to two tags (open and close, as shown above), but that didn't make any difference.

The relevant CSS seems to be:

```
.ui-icon
{
    display: block;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.ui-icon
{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url("images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png");
}

.ui-icon-plusthick 
{
    background-position: -32px -128px;
}
```

I tried changing the display: block to inline-block and other things, but it gets worse if I do.

Edit 3:
Nevermind, I screwed up the code, it should have been:

```
 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" 
             style="display: inline-block"></span>Hello World</div>
```

And that works fine.  (I misspelled "display")

Comment: Can you send us a link to view the issue? I'm sure you have some css some where that is throwing it off. Check it with a web inspector in either chrome, firefox or safari

Comment: No, I don't have a place that can host it on the internet.  The CSS file is part of the standard download though for themeroller, so I was hoping someone else might have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spans are not self closing must have a `</span>` to close it

[span element on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/span)

use:

```
<div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"></span>Hello World</div>
```

instead of:

```
<div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"/>Hello World</div>
```

Comment: That's slightly better.  That gets me the + icon on one line and the "Hello World" on the next line down.  Still not right, but it's something.

Comment: Correcting the span, and adding an "inline-block" to it did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where did you close the span?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
                      href="/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick">&nbsp;</span>Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```